# Solid background for the entire subplot using multiplot in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot two overlaping figures (one "big" and another smaller "zoomed-in"). The thing is I can't have a solid background on the entire "small" figure, meaning including labels, ticks labels, etc.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Here is a SWE of my problem (**EDITED being closer to my problem**):

```
reset
set multiplot
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
set size 0.4,0.4
set origin 0.6,0.5
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 behind fc rgb "#04AA40"
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
unset multiplot
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use almost exactly the same code as you posted, but change the multiplot commands and the coordinates so that the rectangle you make overlaps the labels of the figure as well:

```
reset
set multiplot title "Plot 1"
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0.45,0.45 to graph 1.1,1.1 front fc rgb "#04AA40"
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
unset object 1
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0.45,0.45
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
unset multiplot
```

If that doesn't work, can you explain why you can't have a background on the entire small figure, as you say?

Comment: I modify my SWE in order to be closer to my real problem. The problem is that the green rectangle doesn't include ticks and axis label.

Comment: Hmm.  Did you try my example?  The difference in mine is that I put the green rectangle on the big plot and then make the small plot in the green rectangle.  It appears to be a purposeful constraint that gnuplot can't draw shapes outside the plot area, so you might not be able to define the green rectangle automatically relative to the size/position of the small plot.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry. I though I try your example, but in fact, I run again mine ;-) This is close of what I want, but I am surprised that gnuplot doesn't know the bounding box of each graph (or at least, there no way to get them). Maybe you have an idea of how can I compute them from variables like width,height,xorig,yorig ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know any gnuplot internal variables to deal with the plot bounding box.  The main limitation here seems to be that objects can't extend beyond the plot border.

Comment: Have you seen my own answer ? I thing what I need is a way to get the computed margins of gnuplot... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my own question by this code which is the closest thing I am looking for, but still not happy with it. If anybody has an idea of how I can get the computed margins automatically, this answer could be the one...

```
reset
set multiplot title "Plot 1"
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
xorig_sub=.1
yorig_sub=.5
width_sub=.35
height_sub=.35
lmarg_sub=0.09
bmarg_sub=0.06
rmarg_sub=0.025
tmarg_sub=0.02
xmin=xorig_sub
xmax=xorig_sub+width_sub+rmarg_sub+lmarg_sub
ymin=yorig_sub
ymax=yorig_sub+height_sub+tmarg_sub+bmarg_sub
set object 1 rectangle front from screen xmin,ymin to screen xmax,ymax fc rgb "#04AA40" fs solid
clear
replot
unset object 1
set lmargin at screen xmin+lmarg_sub
set rmargin at screen xmax-rmarg_sub
set bmargin at screen ymin+bmarg_sub
set tmargin at screen ymax-tmarg_sub
set size width_sub,height_sub        # set the size of the second plot in plot units
set origin xorig_sub,yorig_sub       # set the origin for the second plot in plot units
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
unset multiplot
```

Comment: I just stumbled across your Q/A. Just as a clarification: Which of the above margins do you want to *compute automatically*?

Comment: @Schorsch Looking at the subject of this topic, I would like to have a transparent background of the whole subplot in order to have my axis titles above it. In my example, I have to tell gnuplot what are the margins of the subplot in order to satisfy my request. So my question is how can I do such thing in an automatic process ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and saw the post. It might be a bit late in the game, but for the sake of completeness:

```
reset
set multiplot
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
set size 0.4,0.4
set origin 0.6,0.5
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb "#04AA40" fillstyle solid 0.0 noborder
set ticks front
plot sin(x)/x ls -1
unset multiplot
```

Works with gnuplot 5.0.